# Hive consolidation query / join

Tags: sql, join, group-by, hive

Im looking to create a linked table based on the input from two columns X, Y. If they are linked by either X or Y, then they are the same user.

```
   X   |   Y        |  output |
-------+-------     |---------|
   1   |   a        |   u1    |
   2   |   b        |   u2    |
   2   |   c        |   u2    |
   3   |   d   ->   |   u3    |
   4   |   e        |   u2    |
   4   |   b        |   u2    |
   5   |   -        |   u3    |
   5   |   d        |   u3    |
```

IE: X(2) and X(4) are linked by Y(b) etc

Any help would be amazing. I've tried a number of group by, joins and unions combinations but no luck / PEBCAK. I also tried collect_set(Y) then explode, but no dice. Even if it cant be done, that will be useful information.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The generic way to solve this problem in SQL uses a recursive CTE.  Hive does not support recursive CTEs.

That leaves you with less-than-perfect alternatives.  This is a graph walking algorithm, and -- if you know that there are not too many connections between users -- then you can use explicit `join`s:

```
select t1.x, t1.y,
       min(least(coalesce(t2.x, t1.x), coalesce(t3.x, t1.x), coalesce(t4.x, t1.x))) as grp
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.x = t2.y left join
     t t3
     on t2.x = t3.y left join
     t t4
     on t3.x = t4.y
group by t1.x, t1.y
```